# PyDSTool on Windows 7 installation

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I have failed to install PyDStool properly on Windows. Please help. (I have it running no problem on Linux, given the install script that is now available.)

```
import PyDSTool
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-a214100b00aa>", line 1, in <module>
    import PyDSTool

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydstool-0.88.140328-py2.7.egg\PyDSTool\__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    from .Events import *

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydstool-0.88.140328-py2.7.egg\PyDSTool\Events.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .Variable import *

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydstool-0.88.140328-py2.7.egg\PyDSTool\Variable.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .utils import *

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydstool-0.88.140328-py2.7.egg\PyDSTool\utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .common import *

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydstool-0.88.140328-py2.7.egg\PyDSTool\common.py", line 53, in <module>
    import fixedpickle as pickle

ImportError: No module named fixedpickle
```

Comment: Hi - You posted this question twice (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515710/importerror-no-module-named-fixedpickle-when-running-pydstool-on-windows-7/28574981#28574981) and it is now answered. Please accept the answer there, as you said that solution worked, and remove this redundant question.

Comment: Thanks. I had wanted to do this, but had too little power to mark a duplicate.