# ImportError: No module named fixedpickle when running PyDsTool on Windows 7

Tags: python, scientific-computing

I have downloaded PyDsTool for Windows. And I believe I have pointed python in the correct location. But I get the following error

```
from PyDSTool import *
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-7b811358a37e>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyDSTool import *

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydstool-0.88.140328-py2.7.egg\PyDSTool\__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    from .Events import *

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydstool-0.88.140328-py2.7.egg\PyDSTool\Events.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .Variable import *

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydstool-0.88.140328-py2.7.egg\PyDSTool\Variable.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .utils import *

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydstool-0.88.140328-py2.7.egg\PyDSTool\utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .common import *

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydstool-0.88.140328-py2.7.egg\PyDSTool\common.py", line 53, in <module>
    import fixedpickle as pickle

ImportError: No module named fixedpickle
```

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem through uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda. Otherwise the installation of PyDsTools is very simple. It is not really installation at all, just unpack the zip folder and make sure it is in your python path (also add its parent directories to the python path). This may be done through Spyder IDE. Click tools> pythonpath

I received some assistance from the Sourceforge support thread for the PyDStool project [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pydstool/discussion/472291/thread/b4d36830/)

Comment: Note that version 0.90 onwards (Jan 2015) of PyDSTool does have a proper installer now. In any case, reinstalling anaconda is the solution here.  The wrong version of PyDSTool is being used here and there's some kind of conflict in the anaconda system.

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of the installer on Linux and had no problems installing with it from the Git repo on a linux box. The above problem arose on windows. Do you mean there is now an installer for Windows? Eitherway it is working now, so all hypothetical.

Comment: The newest release (on both sourceforge and git) is inherently multi-platform since you can use pip or simply "python setup.py install" to install the package on any of the major platforms.